# display lowest 10 values on barchart using javascript

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

I tried to display top 10 and bottom 10 values of population on bar chart.

Top 10 values displayed successfully but I didn't get that how to display bottom 10 values on bar chart.

I used following code to display top 10 values on bar chart:

```
 d3.csv("{% static 'csv/healthdata.csv' %}", function (error, csv) {
     var data = crossfilter(csv);
     var company = data.dimension(function (d) {
             return d["County_Name"];
         });
     var companyGroup = company.group().reduceSum(function (d) {
             return d["Population"];
         });

     bottomChart.width(300)
         .height(300)
         .margins({
             top: 20,
             left: 10,
             right: 10,
             bottom: 20
         })
         .dimension(company)
         .group(companyGroup)
         // assign colors to each value in the x scale domain
         .ordinalColors(['#3182bd', '#6baed6', '#9ecae1', '#c6dbef', '#dadaeb'])
         .elasticX(true)
         .ordering(function (d) {
         return -d.value;
     })
     .xAxis().ticks(4);

     bottomChart.data(function (group) {
         return group.top(10);
     });

     dc.renderAll();
     d3.selectAll(".bar").call(barTip);
     d3.selectAll(".bar").on('mouseover', barTip.show)
     .on('mouseout', barTip.hide);
 });
```

Please help me to display lowest 10 values.

Comment: You have a function that can return the top N items. It can also deliver the bottom N items. You only must do one thing first. Think.

Comment: I tried it by changing order from descending to ascending but it does'nt works..

Comment: Changing the order is the right approach. I just don't see any code that does that in your sample...?

Comment: SO won't let me mark this as a duplicate because the answer(s) weren't accepted, but see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23215610/how-to-display-bottom-data-for-row-chart-using-dc-js